# Prevent User Control from being resized during runtime

Tags: vb.net

I have problem in using user control in vb.net. Everytime I run the program the user control was being resized. Can anybody help me on how to stop the user control being resized during runtime?

I am looking for something like Locking the property of the form but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the MAXIMUM and MINIMUM size of your UserControl ?

Comment: I haven't but how can I set it?

Comment: In your usercontrols property grid. Or you can do it programmatically.

Comment: @Jessa .. Have you set your `FormBorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` ?

Comment: @matzone ... No, The formBorderStyle was set to FixedToolWindow.

Comment: @Mark Hall... Sir, the UserControl disappear everytime I set the Maximum and Minimum Size of it.

Comment: @Jessa .. If you didn't need `FixedToolWindow` .. you may change it to `FixedSingle` ..

Answer (score 2):

Your usercontrol has AutoScaleMode property. Try to check this property!

I had a similar problem. AutoScaleMode property in my `usercontrol` was `default` in `Font`. My font was 9pt, but the parent control had 13pt font. So the size of the controls in my `usercontrol` auto scales with ratio 13/9.

Answer (score 1):

couple of things to check:

- do you use docking? - it will resize following parent control if yes
- do you use anchor? - it sometimes gives odd behavior too
- some controls have AutoSize property, did you set it true or is it by
  default true?
- some controls have AutoWidthInLayoutControl, did you
  set it true or is it by default true?

another try, some controls do have Maximum and Minimum size, set these values to your desired if necessary.

Comment: I haven't use docking and anchor and the autosize property of the user control was set to false by default. The maximum and minimum size of it was also set to 0 by default. Is it possible that the problem was the form where I load the user control?

Comment: Yes it's possible, for example, using FixedSingle for the form's border style as mentioned by Matzone... and also, do check the parent control, for example, if you put this control into a TableLayoutControl or splitter control